# Best way to get around fork() with MingW 64?

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, mingw, fork

I've gone through a dozen links about how Windows don't have `fork()` and how one should use `CreateProcess` or `CreateThread` to try to get around the problem, but time and risk is not permitted to rewrite a giant piece of legacy code...

Is there a fast/simple way to get the `fork` stuff to work in Windows? I've also read a dozen page about using `cygwin` but I've just converted some other libraries to be "cygwin free" so I would like to not go back there if possible.

BTW, most of the links I read were pretty old, all dated back from 2008 through 2011... Wondering if theres any new workaround.

Comment: No.  `fork` is fundamentally incompatible with the Win32 process model.  Cygwin manages to fake it, but the procedure is both complicated and fragile.  Your best bet IMO is to run the legacy code in a VM running UNIX.

Comment: (Or there is the POSIX subsystem, but I'm not sure of its current status and I don't think I've *ever* seen proper documentation on how to use it.)